# Calling function in one MDB from another MDB

Tags: ms-access, vba

We have developed a consolidation function that will be used by other processes and want to position the function in its own MDB (call it "remote") so that it can be referenced and called from "caller.mdb" when its needed. The function is designed to return an array and works great when executed called directly from within "remote." However, with "remote" properly referenced in the "caller" VBA project, when "caller" makes the call the function returns errors. We get a variety of errors such as

```
3078: Jet cannot find the input table or query
```

QUESTION. Within "remote", how does one properly set references to the db and its local objects (e.g. one table and several queries including INSERT and UPDATE queries)? CurrentDB is apparently not the answer; we have also experimented with the AccessObject and CodeData objects. "Remote" and "caller" currently reside on the same drive, so that wouldn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of CurrentDb you could use with CodeDb wich points to the mdb currently executing the code.

`Set db = CodeDb`

Comment: Outstanding. Hadn't seen this reference previously. Had to refactor a few lines, but its working great now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The way Access itself does this (with all the wizards, which are all programmed in Access), is to use Application.Run. It does mean the code you're calling has to be a function, though it doesn't matter what it returns. Application.Run requires no references, just a path:

```
  Application.Run("MyCodeDatabase.MyFunction()")
```

Obviously, if the code database is not in the path that Access uses (which includes its own app folders (including the app-specific folders in the user's profile) and the folder where your main application front end is stored), you'll need to specify the full path.

Application.Run() is a function that returns a value, but it is typed as variant. This may or may not work with your array. It's not clear from the object browser whether or not the arguments are passed ByVal or ByRef, but if they are ByRef (which is what I'd expect), you might just pass the array in and let the function work on it and then use it after the code in the remote database has completed.

On the other hand, the arguments are probably variants, so there's not much difference between that approach and just using the structure returned by Application.Run().

Comment: I give this one points so it would've been nice to know why osmeone took points away from this answer.

Comment: It's the documented and tried-and-true way to use code databases, so I have no idea why somebody would vote it down. Maybe I didn't answer the right question.

Comment: Would the people who vote this down please explain how it's not a valid answer to the question?

Comment: Is it possible to pass the array ByVal?

Comment: I would guess that if the function in your library database has the parameter defined as ByVal, it will be executed ByVal, even though the intervening Application.Run() function is likely going to pass ByRef. But I'm not sure I understand what ByVal would mean with an array -- I've only passed complex data types ByRef, not because I want to operate on them in the function/sub and then get the results back, but just because I can't quite wrap my head around what passing an array (or an object) ByVal would actually mean.

Answer (score 1):

Marcand gave you the answer to your immediate question.   There are other problems and irritations when it comes to using add-ins or referenced Access databases.   See my [Add-in Tips, Hints and Gotchas](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/addins.htm) page.

Comment: Could you quote some relevant parts from your page here? Links may die, and without its content this post is merely a comment to the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of differences and nuances to calling forms and functions through a reference in a another MDB or ADP. I have run into issues in both situations, and what you are referring to as the "remote" database, I refer to as a central library.

At my Tips and Tricks page at http://www.mooresw.com/tips.php, I have pages devoted to programatically changing references, getting Access to search for the referenced file instead of having a broken reference, and calling forms through a reference.

Programatically changing references is needed when you publish the database from the development environment to the user or production environment.  When working in the development folder, it's fine for the program to have a reference to the central library directly, but we wouldn't want code that 20 users are running tying up the central library in our development area.  (An MDB file opened through a reference gets locked just as though your users were opening it directly)

The situation of running a form in a central library (or "remote" database) where there are no links or tables can be tricky.  In that situation I've chosen to open a connection to the "caller.mdb" using ADO code with a Jet connection string in the open event of the forms. Doing so provides the ability for the code in the form (or functions in the library) to gain access to the tables and queries in the calling mdb.

For further information, see my pages at the tips link above, and in particular, see:

http://www.mooresw.com/call_a_form_in_another_MDB_through_a_reference.php

which I believe is most relevant to your situation.