# Calling a function in one Access VBA program from another Access VBA program

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to call a function in one stand-alone Access VBA program (with its own UI) from another stand-alone Access VBA program (with its own UI).   I know how to do this to invoke a function in WORD, but, in this case, my own Access VBA program would take the place of WORD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a centralized VBA module in multiple Access databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168674/using-a-centralized-vba-module-in-multiple-access-databases) Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319539/call-a-sub-from-a-subroutine-in-another-access-database Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455829/calling-function-in-one-mdb-from-another-mdb

Comment: Fantastic!   Just what I needed.  Thank you for the quick response.   When I saw your answer, I was deep in the weeds reading how to create COM interfaces, which was getting very complicated.   Thank you, thank you, thank you!    Question:  How do I give credit for this to you?

Comment: No credit if I don't write an answer and since there are already adequate answers, I am not doing another. I expect this question will eventually get closed because it is a duplicate.